# Get result code of adb shell command

Tags: android, shell, adb, exit-code

How should I get `$?` of `adb shell <command>`?

I would like to check the result of `adb shell mkdir /xxx`.

I executed `mkdir` command by `adb shell` and failed but the result of `$?` is `0`.

```
$ adb shell mkdir /xxx
mkdir failed for /xxx, Read-only file system
$ adb shell echo $?
0

$ adb shell "mkdir /xxx; echo $?"
mkdir failed for /xxx, Read-only file system
0
```

I would like to get the result code of `adb shell <command>` **but not in the interactive mode** like below:

```
$ adb shell
shell@android:/ $ mkdir /xxx
mkdir failed for /xxx, Read-only file system
255|shell@android:/ $ echo $?
255
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do:

```
$ adb shell 'mkdir /xxx; echo $?'
mkdir failed for /xxx, Read-only file system
255
```

**Notice the single quotes**, otherwise `$?` is evaluated before reaching adb.

Comment: Yeah, you are just having trouble with the shell expansion rules. Check the [expansion man page](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Comment: After try, I find that `adb shell 'mkdir /xxx; echo $?'` worked, but `adb shell "mkdir /xxx; echo $?"` not work, strange.

Comment: Not strange at all, try `$ echo adb shell "mkdir /xxx; echo $?" adb shell mkdir /xxx; echo 0`, (check the `0`); the double quotes allow the expansion of `$?` before invoking `adb`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an older emulator, then `adb shell` does not return the exit value.  Then you have to use `adb shell 'false; echo $?'` like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17480194/306864

In newer emulators, it works properly, then you can do `adb shell false || echo failed`.  Here's how I tested:

```sh
$ adb -e android-22 shell false; echo $?
0
$ adb -e android-22 shell 'false; echo $?'
1
$ adb -e android-29 shell false; echo $?
1
$ adb -e android-29 shell 'false; echo $?'
1
```

Comment: In 2023 is it still impossible to natively get the exit status of the command from `adb shell`?

Comment: `adb shell` is not an emulator. And which version of adb are you referring to?